# Extra spaces when mixing beamercolorbox and tikzpicture

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer, layout

I am trying to create custom beamer blocks for a template using a `tikzpicture` for the title of the block and a `beamercolorbox` for the body.

Here is a MCVE:

```
\documentclass[t]{beamer}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{calc}

\setbeamercolor{block body}{fg = black, bg=blue!10}
\setbeamertemplate{block begin}{%
  \tikz\node[text width=\textwidth{} - .4cm, inner sep=.2cm, fill=blue]{
    \color{white}\insertblocktitle};
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[leftskip=.2cm, rightskip=.2cm, dp=1ex, vmode]{block body}%
    \vspace*{0.15cm}
}

\setbeamertemplate{block end}{%
\end{beamercolorbox}
}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
  \begin{block}{Default}
    Content.
  \end{block}

  Some text after\ldots{}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

I have two problems with the above code:

1. There is a small space between the `tikzpicture` and the `beamercolorbox` that I would like to get rid of... I could use a negative `vspace`, but not knowing where the space comes from, I do not want to put a random value.
2. Combining the tikzpicture with the `beamercolorbox` creates extra space below the block... Removing the `tikzpicture` or the `beamercolorbox` fix the issue, but I need both.

Here is the output I get:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I found out how to fix both issues with a simple change right after posting this... You need to separate the `tikzpicture` and the `beamercolorbox` into two latex "paragraph" and use `nointerlineskip`:

```
}; % End of the tikz picture

\nointerlineskip%
\begin{beamercolorbox}
```

The extra blank line is required for this to work.